# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java-6, ntdll, microfocus

Have tried the solution from different thread from stack overflow and other community forums but didn't find the solution of the below issue. I have both JDK 1.7 - 64 bit and JDK 1.6 - 32 bit installed.

```
        # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
        #
        #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7719748e, pid=12248, tid=9852
        #
        # JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
        # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
        # Problematic frame:
        # C  [ntdll.dll+0x3748e]
        #
        # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
        #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
        # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
        # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
        #

        ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

        Current thread (0x4d2ce800):  JavaThread "COBOL_VERIFY-60" [_thread_in_native, id=9852, stack(0x4c930000,0x4c980000)]

        siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xfffffff8

        Registers:
        EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00008f07, EDX=0x00100000
        ESP=0x4c97ed40, EBP=0x4c97ed6c, ESI=0x4d789bd8, EDI=0x4cd70000
        EIP=0x7719748e, EFLAGS=0x00010206

        Top of Stack: (sp=0x4c97ed40)
        0x4c97ed40:   00004640 4cd70000 4d789bd8 00008f07
        0x4c97ed50:   00100000 4d740000 000007ff 4cd700c4
        0x4c97ed60:   58585858 4cd707d0 00008f07 4c97edac
        0x4c97ed70:   7719dcc0 4cd70000 01789bd8 00008f07
        0x4c97ed80:   4cd70000 00000000 4d789bd8 00000000
        0x4c97ed90:   0a01000b 58585858 58585858 58585858
        0x4c97eda0:   58585858 58585800 58585858 4c97eea4
        0x4c97edb0:   7719436f 4d789bd8 4d789bd8 00008f07 

        Instructions: (pc=0x7719748e)
        0x7719746e:   04 00 83 78 08 00 74 02 03 c9 8b 40 20 8b 04 88
        0x7719747e:   39 45 f0 74 33 8b 7d 08 85 d2 0f 84 16 12 04 00
        0x7719748e:   8b 48 f8 8b 57 4c 85 d1 74 03 33 4f 50 0f b7 c9
        0x7719749e:   0f b7 d9 0f b7 4d fc 2b cb 85 c9 0f 8e 5c 01 00 


        Register to memory mapping:

        EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
        EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
        ECX=0x00008f07 is an unknown value
        EDX=0x00100000 is an unknown value
        ESP=0x4c97ed40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4d2ce800
        EBP=0x4c97ed6c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4d2ce800
        ESI=0x4d789bd8 is an unknown value
        EDI=0x4cd70000 is an unknown value


        Stack: [0x4c930000,0x4c980000],  sp=0x4c97ed40,  free space=315k
        Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
        C  [ntdll.dll+0x3748e]  LdrUnlockLoaderLock+0x66a
        C  [ntdll.dll+0x3dcc0]  RtlIntegerToUnicodeString+0xfb
        C  [ntdll.dll+0x3436f]  RtlInitializeCriticalSection+0x11f
        C  [ntdll.dll+0x32b65]  RtlQueryPerformanceCounter+0x281
        C  [kernel32.dll+0x114bd]  HeapFree+0x14

        Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
        j  com.microfocus.cobol.RuntimeSystem.ccall(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;[I)I+0
        j  com.microfocus.cobol.RuntimeSystem.cobthreadtidy()I+4
        j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
        v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

        ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

        Java Threads: ( => current thread )
        =>0x4d2ce800 JavaThread "COBOL_VERIFY-60" [_thread_in_native, id=9852, stack(0x4c930000,0x4c980000)]
          0x4d2cd000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-24" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10012, stack(0x4ec90000,0x4ece0000)]
          0x4d2cdc00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-23" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9504, stack(0x4ee40000,0x4ee90000)]
          0x4d2cd800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-22" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7444, stack(0x4edb0000,0x4ee00000)]
          0x4d2cc800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-21" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11412, stack(0x4ec00000,0x4ec50000)]
          0x4d5cf800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-20" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12220, stack(0x4e930000,0x4e980000)]
          0x4d2cc400 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9444, stack(0x4ea50000,0x4eaa0000)]
          0x4d2cbc00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-18" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7792, stack(0x4e9c0000,0x4ea10000)]
          0x4d5d5c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12948, stack(0x4e8a0000,0x4e8f0000)]
          0x4d5d5800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12156, stack(0x4ed60000,0x4edb0000)]
          0x4d5d5000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7728, stack(0x4e7e0000,0x4e830000)]
          0x4d5d4c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11384, stack(0x4e750000,0x4e7a0000)]
          0x4d5d4400 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11920, stack(0x4e6c0000,0x4e710000)]
          0x4d5d3c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7724, stack(0x4e630000,0x4e680000)]
          0x4d5d3800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12820, stack(0x4e5a0000,0x4e5f0000)]
          0x4d5d3000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=624, stack(0x4e510000,0x4e560000)]
          0x4d5d2c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11896, stack(0x4e480000,0x4e4d0000)]
          0x4d5d2400 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1536, stack(0x4e3f0000,0x4e440000)]
          0x4d5d2000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9804, stack(0x4e360000,0x4e3b0000)]
          0x4d5d0c00 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=11748, stack(0x4ca50000,0x4caa0000)]
          0x4d5d0000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11400, stack(0x4c9c0000,0x4ca10000)]
          0x4d5cf400 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10300, stack(0x4c8a0000,0x4c8f0000)]
          0x4d68e000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12716, stack(0x4c810000,0x4c860000)]
          0x4d601000 JavaThread "OracleTimeoutPollingThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11576, stack(0x4c780000,0x4c7d0000)]
          0x4d716000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11692, stack(0x4c6a0000,0x4c6f0000)]
          0x4d065c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12432, stack(0x4c610000,0x4c660000)]
          0x4bd82800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10908, stack(0x4c2a0000,0x4c2f0000)]
          0x4bd84800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8584, stack(0x4c160000,0x4c1b0000)]
          0x026c5000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9508, stack(0x4b920000,0x4b970000)]
          0x026bd400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11812, stack(0x4b890000,0x4b8e0000)]
          0x026ba400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9876, stack(0x4b800000,0x4b850000)]
          0x026b7000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8276, stack(0x4b770000,0x4b7c0000)]
          0x02687000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9532, stack(0x4b6e0000,0x4b730000)]
          0x02682400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12744, stack(0x4b650000,0x4b6a0000)]
          0x02601800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=1888, stack(0x025b0000,0x02600000)]

        Other Threads:
          0x0267ec00 VMThread [stack: 0x4b5c0000,0x4b610000] [id=10572]
          0x026dec00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x4b9b0000,0x4ba00000] [id=8856]

        VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

        VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

        Heap
         def new generation   total 215040K, used 1911K [0x04780000, 0x130d0000, 0x130d0000)
          eden space 191168K,   1% used [0x04780000, 0x0495dee8, 0x10230000)
          from space 23872K,   0% used [0x10230000, 0x10230000, 0x11980000)
          to   space 23872K,   0% used [0x11980000, 0x11980000, 0x130d0000)
         tenured generation   total 477888K, used 179691K [0x130d0000, 0x30380000, 0x30380000)
           the space 477888K,  37% used [0x130d0000, 0x1e04ae00, 0x1e04ae00, 0x30380000)
         compacting perm gen  total 409600K, used 107408K [0x30380000, 0x49380000, 0x49380000)
           the space 409600K,  26% used [0x30380000, 0x36c64020, 0x36c64200, 0x49380000)
        No shared spaces configured.

        Code Cache  [0x02700000, 0x02f90000, 0x04700000)
         total_blobs=4640 nmethods=4446 adapters=128 free_code_cache=24611968 largest_free_block=384

        Dynamic libraries:
        0x00400000 - 0x00425000     E:\app\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe
        0x77160000 - 0x772e0000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
        0x759a0000 - 0x75ab0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
        0x76130000 - 0x76177000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
        0x75ca0000 - 0x75d40000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
        0x76b90000 - 0x76c3c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
        0x75e90000 - 0x75ea9000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
        0x75da0000 - 0x75e90000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
        0x74c70000 - 0x74cd0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
        0x74c60000 - 0x74c6c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
        0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     E:\app\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
        0x6d810000 - 0x6dac0000     E:\app\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll
        0x76660000 - 0x76760000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
        0x75c10000 - 0x75ca0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
        0x75f60000 - 0x75f6a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
        0x76420000 - 0x764bd000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
        0x731b0000 - 0x731e2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
        0x75d40000 - 0x75da0000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
        0x76a20000 - 0x76aec000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
        0x73e50000 - 0x73e9c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
        0x6d7c0000 - 0x6d7cc000     E:\app\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
        0x6d330000 - 0x6d34f000     E:\app\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
        0x6d800000 - 0x6d80f000     E:\app\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
        0x6d560000 - 0x6d569000     E:\app\Java\jre6\bin\management.dll
        0x6d610000 - 0x6d623000     E:\app\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
        0x76d20000 - 0x76d55000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
        0x74d40000 - 0x74d46000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
        0x74540000 - 0x7457c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
        0x72a20000 - 0x72a26000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
        0x74530000 - 0x74535000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
        0x73eb0000 - 0x73ef4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
        0x73c30000 - 0x73c4c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
        0x73c20000 - 0x73c27000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
        0x73bd0000 - 0x73bd6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
        0x73be0000 - 0x73c18000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
        0x74300000 - 0x74317000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
        0x74010000 - 0x7404b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
        0x73990000 - 0x739a7000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
        0x73980000 - 0x7398b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
        0x73c70000 - 0x73c80000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
        0x73c60000 - 0x73c70000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
        0x73c50000 - 0x73c58000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
        0x6d630000 - 0x6d639000     E:\app\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
        0x61000000 - 0x6100c000     E:\\app\MicroFocus\NetExpress5.1\Base\Bin\CBLJVM_SUN.DLL
        0x60000000 - 0x600b0000     E:\\app\MicroFocus\NetExpress5.1\Base\Bin\cblrtsm.dll
        0x4be00000 - 0x4be0c000     E:\app\MicroFocus\NetExpress5.1\Base\BIN\cbljvm_sun.dll
        0x4bf70000 - 0x4bf7d000     E:\app\MicroFocus\NetExpress5.1\Base\BIN\javaclass.dll
        0x4bf80000 - 0x4bf94000     E:\app\MicroFocus\NetExpress5.1\Base\BIN\oopsm.dll
        0x4c1b0000 - 0x4c1b7000     E:\app\MicroFocus\NetExpress5.1\Base\BIN\MFOM.DLL
        0x4c1c0000 - 0x4c1c9000     E:\app\MicroFocus\NetExpress5.1\Base\BIN\class.dll
        0x4cd80000 - 0x4ce31000     E:\app\MicroFocus\NetExpress5.1\Base\BIN\classm.dll
        0x4cd10000 - 0x4cd24000     E:\app\MicroFocus\NetExpress5.1\Base\BIN\MFJAVAM.DLL


        VM Arguments:
        jvm_args: -Xms700M -Xmx700M -XX:PermSize=400M -XX:MaxPermSize=400M 
        Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

        Environment Variables:
        JAVA_HOME=C:\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
        CLASSPATH=E:\app\MicroFocus\NetExpress5.1\Base\BIN\mfcobol.jar;.;LASSPATH
        USERNAME=navhad
        SHELL=c:/mksnt/mksnt/sh.exe
        DISPLAY=:0.0
        OS=Windows_NT
        PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel



        ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

        OS: Windows NT 6.1 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

        CPU:total 32 (12 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 62 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

        Memory: 4k page, physical 268376140k(253130084k free), swap 536750444k(519531228k free)

        vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.45-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_45-b06), built on Mar 26 2013 13:40:03 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

        time: Wed Dec 16 11:07:59 2015
        elapsed time: 160 seconds
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Who upvoted this?!

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific?

Comment: This is one of those questions that would deserve a canonical answer.

Comment: @IIGala :  I have setup hudson with different jdk versions, jdk1.7_80-64 bit and jdk1.6_45- 32 bit.(operating system is Windows NT 6.1 , 64 bit). I have configured masterjob and slave jobs. I have set one slave job which is set to use jdk1.6-32 bit which internally invokes cobol jvm. When I am executing slave job with jdk1.6 hudson generates log as above. I searched and found that issue is due to ntdll.dll as it is crashing 32-bit jvm.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got solution after re-installing jdk. Installed JDK 1.7 on slave machine was corrupted due to which jdk was failing to invoke na. After reinstalling same JDK version it worked.Thanks all.

Comment: (Resolved) I work with arduino library (.jar). I have the same problem. I've just removed all versions jdk, netbeans, jre,  AND after then only install jre_32 bit! AND after then run MyFile.jar and It seems as already OK OK OK!